# Most efficient way to blur an image in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am blurring the background of an image using the blur method. All the tutorials I have seen show the highest kernel size of (7,7). But that is not blurred enough for what I need it for.

I have used Size(33,33) and it works alright but I would like to go higher so currently I am using Size(77,77). Is this the most efficient way of blurring an image in OpenCV? And is it okay to go that high at all?

Another Idea is run the blur method more than once. with a kernel size of (7,7), but that doesn't seem like it is more efficient.

EDIT:
OpenCV version 3.2

Comment: You can try resizing your image to half (or less) of its original size, blurring with a smaller radius then resizing back up to the original size.

Comment: pyrDown and pyrUp would help with going up and down the resolution pyramid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `cv::stackBlur()`.

It's an addition from v4.7.0. Its performance is almost flat, i.e. independent of kernel size. The pull request contains performance figures: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/20379

- `GaussianBlur(sigmaX=22)` (30 ms)
- `stackBlur(ksize=(101,101))` (0.4 ms)

[image: GaussianBlur]
[image: stackBlur]

Comment: Since I'm using an older version (3.2) that didn't work. I will try reducing the resolution.

Comment: About six iterations of `pyrDown` then six `pyrUp` give the same results as your GaussianBlur or stackBlur. i couldnt tell you how fast it is.

Comment: why are you stuck with v3.2? -- I'd expect pyrDown+up to be fast too. it'll give you octaves, so if you need a specific sigma, you'd apply that on the smallest version, scaled appropriately, then pyrUp. -- if the simple box blur is good enough for you, I think repeated application of that also approaches a gaussian shape

Comment: I am building a custom module for [kurento-media-server](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/writing_modules.html) (version 6.18).

Comment: if `boxBlur` is fast enough but still too ugly for you, you can run several smaller passes of it. that'll approach something gaussian but I'm not sure how that behaves in the 2D case, only the 1D case.